# default for persistence.xml variable set by environment variable

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, environment-variables

tl;dr: I want to fill a variable in the `persistence.xml` with an environment variable, or have it be a previously defined default if no such environment variable exists.

---

I want to set the default scheme of Hibernate in my persistence.xml dynamically on start-up in Docker.
Therefore i added a variable into the following property, which can be set by using an environment variable:

```
<property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="${env.DB_SCHEME}"/>
```

This works perfectly fine for the docker environment, but for the non-docker environment i need some kind of default value that gets injected.

Sadly i cant use something like this, because it is not supported:

```
<property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="${env.DB_SCHEMA:my_default_scheme}"/>
```

I also tried adding a property `env.DB_SCHEME` to the Maven properties of the project,
but that way it always uses the value from Maven and i can't override it with environment variables anymore.

Another thing i read about was to use the filtering option from the resource plugin in Maven. That way i could replace the variable with a pre-defined value.
But that way i have to select a profile while building and it's not possible to change at runtime.

Further i tried doing it programatically. Therefore i took the entityManager of my persistence-unit and checked, whether the environment-variable was set or not.
If it was set (only while using the docker environment) it should have placed the `${env.DB_SCHEME}` in the value of the property.
Otherwise it could have placed `${DB_SCHEME}` in it, so that the property from Maven could later overwrite it.
But somehow, the properties aren't set. Maybe the code is executed too late, because the property hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" is set to validate.

Comment: would like to use this question to ask that will use `:-` work for your case? or `:` and `:-` are the same? can `${env.DB_SCHEMA:-my_default_scheme}` work?

Comment: I have never seen `:-` being used before. What is that syntax, can you elaborate?

Comment: in your example, its ${env.DB_SCHEMA:-my_default_scheme}
ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122845/using-a-b-for-variable-assignment-in-scripts/122878

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Payara application container (version >= `4.1.2.172`), you can user a syntax like this:

```bash
${ENV=PG_DATASOURCE_NAME}
```

My `persistence.xml` file for example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="${ENV=PG_DATASOURCE_NAME}" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>${ENV=PG_DATASOURCE_NAME}</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode" value="NONE" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

More on this topic at [the docs](https://docs.payara.fish/enterprise/docs/5.26.0/documentation/payara-server/server-configuration/var-substitution/usage-of-variables.html).